# image links with functions in php

Tags: php, html, css

i have a question about a function.

```
function &formatName($id, $name, $clanId, $clanSym, $clanCol)
{
    static $cache = array();

    if (!isset($cache[$name])) {
        $cache[$name] = esc($name);

        if ($id !== NULL) {
            $cache[$name] = '<a href="' . esc('player_info.php?target=' . $id) .
             '">' . $cache[$name] . '</a>';
        } else {
            $cache[$name] = "<s>{$cache[$name]}</s>";
        }

        if ($clanId !== NULL && $clanId != 0) {
            $cache[$name] = "(<span style=\"color: #$clanCol;\">" .
             htmlentities($clanSym) . "</span>) " . $cache[$name];
        }
    }

    return $cache[$name];
}
```

//print clickable name of $player

```
function print_name($player)
{
    global $db_name, $user_options;
    static $cache = array();

    if (!isset($cache[$player['login_name']])) {//this user not cached
        $pQuery = mysql_query("select u.login_id, u.login_name, u.clan_id, u.clan_sym_color,u.clan_sym from ${db_name}_users u where u.login_id = '$player[login_id]'");
        $player = mysql_fetch_assoc($pQuery);

        $cache[$player['login_name']] = formatName($player['login_id'],
         $player['login_name'], $player['clan_id'], $player['clan_sym'],
         $player['clan_sym_color']);
    }

    return $cache[$player['login_name']];
}
```

the above functions prints a link with player's name.
i would like to place a table or some sort of decorative background on the link. 
Any way i can do this?
thank you for reading.

Comment: darn it. lol im trying to add a div but its not working either.

Comment: Consider reading about [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change the line:

```
$cache[$name] = '<a href="' . esc('player_info.php?target=' . $id) . '">' . $cache[$name] . '</a>';
```

to

```
$cache[$name] = '<span class="link-decorator">';
$cache[$name] .= '<a href="' . esc('player_info.php?target=' . $id) .
             '">' . $cache[$name] . '</a>';
$cache[$name] .= '</span>';
```

Then you can style the link and the surrounding span using CSS:

```
span.link-decorator { border: 3px solid #789abc; }
span.link-decorator a { color: red; }
span.link-decorator a:hover { color: blue; }
span.link-decorator a:visited { color: green; }
```

Comment: Next reply will be "it does nothing" :-)

Comment: lol, it doesnt work, it does nothing. actually it hides the link altogether.

Comment: There was a typo in my code (fixed now), you should look at the HTML output, eventually pass it to a HTML validator such as the W3C validator (Google will help) and fix the HTML errors that are highlighted.

Comment: i might have been too quick to answer. the css actually does put a clickable background to it. :)

Comment: would i be able to put a div instead?

Answer (score 0):

You could place a span around the link and add styles to that which would give you more flexibility than styling the link.

```
$cache[$name] = '<span style="background-image: url(image.jpg);"><a href="' . esc('player_info.php?target=' . $id) . '">' . $cache[$name] . '</a></span>';
```

Comment: it was example code - you must replace `image.jpg` with a real image on your server...

Comment: and also correct my typos :) but this is exactly the same answer as the chosen one - so forget about it.